# How to Add and show Product Unique code(label) in Listing Page

Tags: magento2, product

I want to customize product listing page with unqiue code (label) same like shown in below picture. add filter by that code of product.
Note  : if Product is assigning to multiple category then code will be different for both category. How can we implement this?
Thanks in Advance

[image: Product Listing with unique code]

Comment: which patter of format you are using to assign the unique-code to product based on categor?

Answer (score 0):

- Make one Text type Attribute of Catalog_Product Using Catalog Adding Attribute or you can use script ,Make sure your Attribute is Filterable With Layred Navigation.

**Use Link:-** `https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html`

- Then Adding Attribute assign in Your all your Category Products.
- Now Open Your `app/design/package/theme/catalog/product/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`
- And Show Your Custom Attribute Value in This File:- (Make Sure you check your layout condition of **Grid View** And **List View**)

And Show Your Attribute in like:-

```
 <?php  echo $_product->getAttributeName(); ?>
```

...

Thanks, Hope This Will Work :-)

Comment: Thanks for response, but as i mentioned that  if Product is assigning to multiple category then code will be show different for each category.

Comment: But One Product has fixed values means one product assigns one values @ni3solanki

Comment: i want to show label (unique code) category wise. so for exam : if product is assigned to 2 category. then code need to show different 
 for 1 category and different for 2th category. @divyesh

Comment: This is not Possible @ni3solanki

Comment: https://ibb.co/jp5RUS  please check this image.can you tell me how to get entity id from that table. you can see product id = 9 assigned to three category. i can use entity id as label code.

Comment: So  It will showing all The assign entity ids as labal  ?

Comment: no, i have category id (current category) in listing page. so can use where clause of category_id + product id .